# RecyclerView messes up child view on scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-studio, view, android-recyclerview

Well i tried to implement the recyclerview into Android Studio like this :

```
public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public String[] dataSet;
public Context context;


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ImageView image;
    public TextView name;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        this.name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);

    }

    public void bindData(Object data){

        String extractedData = (String)data;

        this.name.setText("");
        this.name.setText(extractedData);

        this.image.getLayoutParams().height = getRandomIntInRange(250, 100);

    }

}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


public RecycleViewAdapter(Context context, String[] dataSet){

    this.context = context;
    this.dataSet = dataSet;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.food_view,parent,false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    // Resolves the messed up views after recycling.
    viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.bindData(dataSet[position]);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.length;
}

// Custom method to get a random number between a range
protected int getRandomIntInRange(int max, int min){

    Random rdm = new Random();

    return rdm.nextInt((max-min)+min)+min;
}
```

}

Somehow i noticed that once i scroll up and down the recycled views get messed up...

Heres a Picture without Scrolling :

[normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36nd7.jpg)

And here is one after Scrolling... as you can see totally messed up :

[messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL6MA.png)

Why does this happen and how can i prevent this ? 
Does anyone got a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Well
Adapter is calling `onBindViewHolder()` all times when he must recreate view on the screen. You need to call `getRandomIntInRange()` outside of `onBindViewHolder()`

You could see it:
[image]